# Json Schema Conditional if/Then not working

Tags: json, jsonschema

I'm new to Json Schema validation.   I think the validation should fail, but it passes.   Not sure why the If/then is not forcing the required field.   I believe I formatted the If/Then correctly.

**JSON:**

```
{
    "name": "Battery Wear",
    "triggerAlert": {
        "trigger": "When",
        "timeSpan": 50,
        "timeSpanMeasure": "Hours"
    }
}
```

**SCHEMA:**

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "name",
        "triggerAlert"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "name": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "triggerAlert": {
            "type": "object",
            "required": ["trigger"],
            "properties": {
                "trigger": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "enum": ["Always","When"]
                },
                "numberOfEvents": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "timeSpan": {
                    "type": "integer"
                },
                "timeSpanMeasure": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "if": { "properties": {"trigger": {"enum": ["When"]} } },
            "then": {            
                "required": [
                    "numberOfEvents",
                    "timeSpan",
                    "timeSpanMeasure"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the implementation you are using, you may not have support for these conditionals. `if`/`then`/`else` were only added in specification draft 7.

The schema is correct; the expected error result is:

```
{
  "errors" : [
    {
      "error" : "missing property: numberOfEvents",
      "instanceLocation" : "/triggerAlert",
      "keywordLocation" : "/properties/triggerAlert/then/required"
    },
    {
      "error" : "subschema is not valid",
      "instanceLocation" : "/triggerAlert",
      "keywordLocation" : "/properties/triggerAlert/then"
    },
    {
      "error" : "not all properties are valid",
      "instanceLocation" : "",
      "keywordLocation" : "/properties"
    }
  ],
  "valid" : false
}
```

Comment: I wonder if the issue is with Powershell.   I was running the test using Test-Json from Powershell 7.2.   And using that, the schema does not error.

Comment: The docs for powershell say they use the following implementation for JSON Schema: https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema - The implementation says "draft-04+" which is unhelpful. I can't see the official test suite. I can't tell what versions of JSON Schema are supported, and the tests seem very limited.

Comment: There's a related open issue about `if/then/else` https://github.com/RicoSuter/NJsonSchema/issues/1240

Comment: You should be able to use my library, [JsonSchema.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonSchema.Net/) pretty easily from Powershell.  It's fully compliant.  You can play with it at https://json-everything.net/json-schema.